# Advanced Custom Fields checkbox display value

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I'm struggling with ACF checkboxes, I'm trying to check the array to see if 'car' has been ticked:

```
if( in_array( 'car', the_sub_field('tyres_available') ) )
{
    echo 'some html';
}
```

'car' is one of the checkbox options. If it's ticked I want to echo out some html. At the moment it's outputting the whole array for every checkbox that has been ticked in the field 'tyres_available'.

Any ideas where am I going wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorted. It's `get_sub_field`, not `the_sub_field`:

```
<?php $tyreServices = get_sub_field('tyres_available'); ?>

<?php if(in_array("car", $tyreServices )){ ?>
    Some html
<?php } ?>
```